# Additional citation argument "$(P_{CC})$" in \cite[p. 567, $(P_{CC})$]{book123}

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am trying to do this:

```
 \cite[p. 567, $(P_{CC})$]{book123}
```

> $(P_{CC})$ is the name of a problem on page 567 of  book123.

Unfortunately, this does not work properly. Latex does not like a maths expression inside the brackets.

How to solve this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: It's possible that this breaks in some situations, but in a few simple examples that I just tried this input worked flawlessly. I'm afraid you will have to show us a short example document that reproduces your issue with as little excess code as possible. Otherwise it is almost impossible to say what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

I don't understand the basis for your claim that "Latex does not like a maths expression inside the brackets" [of a citation call-out, preumably]. For sure, the following sample code

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{book123, author = {book123}, title  = {Problems}, year = 3001}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite[p.~567, $(P_{CC})$]{book123}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

produces this result (after running the code thru LaTeX, biber, and LaTeX one once more):

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your effort. The issue I am experiencing is the following: Text after the citation is displayed as if it is in math mode, even though it is not.

Comment: Hmmm, I am unable to reproduce this. E,g., if I append `abc` to `\cite[p.~567, $(P_{CC})$]{book123}` in the sample code above, I get "abc" in normal text-mode letters -- nothing math-like, for sure. Please give a code example from your document that leads to the outcome "Text after the citation is displayed as if it is in math mode".

Comment: It turned out that in the editor the following text , i.e. overleaf, is displayed as if it were in a math environment, but in the compiled PDF the text is displayed normally. Also there is no other error message. In that respect, maybe this is just a small bug in the editor and I'm sorry I didn't notice it earlier. Nevertheless,  thanks for the effort.

Comment: @mathsstudentTUD - Thanks for this update. Overleaf-specific issues are best brought to the attention of the Overleaf helpdesk. By the way, their LaTeX support staff are top-notch.